# Compressing nvarchar(500)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, compression

We have table with more than new 100,000 added every day (SQL Server 2008).

Table has 10 fields but one of them is most heavy
- its saving description of product 500chars. and its set now as nvarchar(500).
the data saved in that field is not only in english, can be in russian,hebrew,arabic,chinese etc.

We cannot rid of this field, is there a way to compress the content and using smaller size than nvarchar(500)

Comment: You need to allow 500 characters for this field, but how many of these characters are typically used?

Answer (score 0):

You can compress the entire table (clustered index) or index itself. Here is how:

```
ALTER TABLE Production.TransactionHistory REBUILD PARTITION = ALL  
WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE); 

ALTER TABLE Production.TransactionHistory REBUILD PARTITION = ALL  
WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = ROW);
```

You can use this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-estimate-data-compression-savings-transact-sql to estimate the space saved with ROW or PAGE compression.